# how to read user sent messages in android having specific time

Tags: android, cursor, sms

I have created a service that reads user messages after every 15 minutes , code is working fine for all messages but the problem is that i want to read messages sent for last 15 minutes not all messages , here is my code for service

```
public class MessageReadingService extends Service {
     ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =   Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
int happy,sad,lonely,joyful=0;
Cursor cur;

 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

                 cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body"}, null, null, "DATE desc");


            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String smsBody = cur.getString(5);
                    String body=smsBody.toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (body.contains("happy") || body.contains("yay") || body.contains("I am well") || body.contains("excited")) {
                        happy++;
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (body.contains("sad") || body.contains("not well") || body.contains("crying")|| body.contains("ill") || body.contains("leave me alone") || body.contains("i hate people")){
                        sad++;

                    }
                    if (body.contains("alone") ||body.contains("lonely") || body.contains("heart broken") || body.contains("Extremely sad")){
                        lonely++;
                    }
                    if (body.contains("joyful") || body.contains("exited") || body.contains("")){
                        joyful++;

                    }

                }
            }
}
    }, 60*15, 60*15, SECONDS);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calendar object and set the condition for where clause

```
private static final int FIFTEEN_MINUTES=  15 * 60 * 1000;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

String[] projection = {"address", "body"};
String whereAddress = "address = ?";
String whereDate = "date BETWEEN " + cal.getTimeInMillis() +
                   " AND " + (cal.getTimeInMillis() + FIFTEEN_MINUTES);
String where = DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere(whereAddress, whereDate);
```

and then use the query like this

```
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(inboxUri,
                                        projection,
                                        where,
                                        new String[]{phoneNumber},
                                        "date DESC");
```

This gets the latest messages of the last 15 minutes.

Comment: Hmm, you didn't quite adapt that example correctly. The `address` shouldn't be considered for what the OP here wants, and using a `Calendar` is more work than is necessary. How about just `String where = "date > " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - FIFTEEN_MINUTES);`?

Comment: @MikeM. "date" keyword will get the time in millis?

Comment: @bravo In the SMS table, yes, the `date` column is in milliseconds.

Comment: Please correct your code first, Sushobh. I would think that @bravo would only want to accept an answer that is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
mSortOrder);
```

You set select criteria to NULL;
Replace mSelectionClause with a WHERE clause: WHERE col = value

```
"date>=" + dateStart.getTime();
```